# How to make row and column containers stack vertically and scale for mobile view with HTML CSS and Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Using the Bootstrap grid system to organize text boxes that are arranged in 2 by 2 formation on a webpage. From the desktop view, the content for the rows and columns looks fine, although it be nice to adjust width easily.

However, when viewing the webpage from a mobile view, the contents of the page does not scale accordingly. The boxes shrink and become very hard to read.

Ideally, when viewing the webpage from mobile, the boxes will automatically resize and stack vertically on top of each other. Essentially, the contents should scale accordingly so that it is easily readable from the phone.

Instead of:
[A][B]
[C][D]

This would be how they should look on mobile.

[A]

[B]

[C]

[D]

What is the best approach to accomplishing this?
Here is a picture for context.

Mobile View:

[image]

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">   
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="container"> <!--bootstrap class-->
            <div class="services">
                <h1>Our <span>Services</span></h1>
                <p>text here</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="service-box">
                        <i class="fa fa-smile-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <h3><span>Box A</span></h3>
                        <p>
                            Text
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="service-box">
                        <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <h3><span>Box B</span></h3>
                    <p><b>List:</b><br>                   
                        1<br>
                        2<br>
                        3<br>
                        4<br>
                        5<br>
                        6<br>
                        7<br>
                        8<br>
                        9<br>
                        10
                    </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
                <div class="row" style="margin-top: 35px">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="service-box">
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                    <h3><span>Box C</span></h3>
                    <p>
                        I<br>
                        II<br>
                        III<br>                       
                    </p>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="service-box">
                    <i class="fa fa-shield"></i>
                    <h3><span>Box D</span></h3>
                    <p>
                        Defender<br>
                    </p>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="home-button"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> HOME</a>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body
{
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0) !important;
}
.services
{
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: xx-large;
}
.services p
{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: x-large;
}
span
{
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff105f, #ffad06);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
}
.service-box
{
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 #ffa709;  
    padding: 15px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    height:100%;
}
.service-box .fa
{
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff105f, #ffad06);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
    font-size: 50px !important;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
p
{
    text-align: justify;
}
.service-box a
{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff105f, #ffad06);
    text-align: center;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: -20px;
    position: absolute;
}

.service-box a .fa
{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 25px !important;
    padding-top: 6px;
}

@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Can you try this code all div col class

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
```